# How to create an input stream from a list of byte[] where each byte[] represent one page of a document (say pdf)

Tags: java, arrays, pdf, file-io, inputstream

From my Java code I am calling a Document Service to get a document from it based on some input parameters. The mime type of the document could be pdf, text or image. The service response is in the form of `List<PageContent>` where each `PageContent` has `byte[]` which represent one page of the document. Now I want to create an input stream for the whole document.

So I thought of collating all the pages like following:

```
List<PageContent> pages = ....//Response from the service
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
for(PageContent page : pages) {
    byte[] data = page.getData();
    bos.write(data);
}
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
```

I still have doubt that it is the right way or not. Should the logic of collating all page to form a single input stream be different based on mime type?

What kind of details do I need to get from Document Service provider which will help me do this?

Comment: *"Should the logic of collating all page to form a single input stream be different based on mime type?"* - Obviously yes. *"each PageContent has byte[] which represent one page"* - How does it represent it?